# getResourceSingleton() Not working multiple time on single call magento 1

Tags: php, api, magento, singleton

We are using Magento 1.
We have used this code:

```
Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/category_tree')->load();

$tree = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/category_tree')->load();
    $root = $tree->getNodeById($rootCategoryId);
                if($root && $root->getId() == 1) { 
                    $root->setName(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Root')); 
                }
                $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection() 
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('name') 
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active','1');
                    //->addAttributeToFilter('display_mode',array('nlike'=>'PAGE'))
                    //->setLoadProductCount(true)
                    //->setProductStoreId($store)
                    //->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu','1');

                $tree->addCollectionData($collection, true);
```

We have created a api, and calling this in widget categories as well as category listing, but its only loading for last one only, not resulting for all calls.

kindly suggest a proper way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is the way a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) works, use model instead.

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_tree')
```

Comment: yes tried that, while we use model `$tree->getNodeById($rootCategoryId);` is not working

Comment: you have not mentioned any error message. but I guess you are trying to access method getNodeById() from category model. while it is only possible through category resource model. this way: Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_tree')

Comment: cool!!! perfect answer!!! `Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_tree') ` worked, thanx alot :)